# DataTables - Ordenação Default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Como faço para uma tabela já vir ordenada por uma determinada coluna no DataTable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto aqui:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 3, 'desc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

onde `order: [[ 3, 'desc' ]]` o 3 significa o número da sua coluna e desc significa que ela vai ordenar do maior para o maior ou do Z para o A, as colunas são numeradas do 0 até as última, da esquerda para direita.

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html